# What Zend View Partial setObjectKey do?

Tags: zend-framework

i am reading zend framework docs on zend view partials

> If your model is an object, you may
>   want to have it passed as an object to
>   the partial script, instead of
>   serializing it to an array of
>   variables. You can do this by setting
>   the 'objectKey' property of the
>   appropriate helper:
>
> ```
> // Tell partial to pass objects as 'model' variable
> $view->partial()->setObjectKey('model');
> ```

but what does this do. when do i use it and how.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not 100% positive on this, but from what I can tell by looking at the source and documentation is that standard behavior for rendering a partial is that values are passed into it in the form of an associative array. This allows the values to be bound to variables using array keys.

```
echo $this->partial('partial.phtml', array ('person' => 'joe');

// in my partial..
<h1><?php echo $this->person; ?></h1>  //<h1>Joe</h1>
```

If you pass an object as the third parameter, (ie, `partial('partial.phtml', $myobject);`), Zend_View_Partial will automatically serialize that object in an associative array, either by a custom implementation of `toArray()` or it will just grab the public properties via `get_object_vars()`.

However, if you want to pass the whole object, *as an object*, you need to set the array key that gets transformed into a variable for the partial to reference.

```
$this->partial()->setObjectKey('myobject');
echo $this->partial('partial.phtml', $myobject);
```

What benefits this approach has over `partial('partial.phtml', array( 'myobject' => $myobject)`, I'm not sure. Or I could be interpreting the documentation wrong.

Comment: +1 yep, that's about it. To understand it easily, open up `Zend/View/Helper/Partial.php` and go to line ~91, there's the whole logic behind this.

Comment: i tried declaring a class with `__toArray()` then i tried using it with and without `setObjectKey()` both does not work (no output). [http://pastebin.com/hNR5KxfA](http://pastebin.com/hNR5KxfA) what do i pass into `setObjectKey()` btw? i used "article". when i used public properties with `stdClass()` it works [http://pastebin.com/TxMLpdrm](http://pastebin.com/TxMLpdrm)

Comment: @jiewming: Just a small correction. If you invoke the partial with `$out = $view->partial('partial.phtml', array ('person' => 'joe');`, then I believe your usage within the view script should be `<?= $this->person ?>`, not `<?= $person ?>`. Similarly, for the invocation  `$out = $view->partial('partial.phtml', $myobject);`, then your usage within the view script would be `<?= $this->myobject->someMethod() ?>`. I also see no difference between using `setObjectKey('myobject')` and `array('myobject' => $myobject)`.

Comment: Just stumbled upon this old post. That approach has (to my understanding) no benefit when using $this->partial(), but it is really useful using $this->partialLoop() if you loop over an array of objects.

Answer (score 0):

Key as in array(key => value)?